# How do I delete a specific year from df

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time, grouping

df.head()

```
          HEAT/HOT WATER
created_date    
2015-12-31  169457.0
2016-12-31  155578.0
2017-12-31  152009.0
2018-12-31  153277.0
2019-12-31  76712.0
```

I would like to delete 2019 from index

I have tried this with no success.

```
df = df[df['created_date'] != '2019']
```

Comment: df = df[df['created_date'].year != 2019].copy()

Comment: @WeNYoBen I don't follow? Why would making a copy help in an assignment?

Comment: @roganjosh check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20625582/how-to-deal-with-settingwithcopywarning-in-pandas, prevent SettingWithCopyWarning

Comment: Well aware of that answer. I'm just not sure how you came to the `.copy()` conclusion from the question

Comment: @WeNYoBen I agree about the Warning and using .copy() but doesnt that only apply when youre setting the df to a new one? in this case the df is remaining the same.

Comment: @ChristianTorres that is just my coding behavior, everyone have their own coding style , like I always do df.loc[1,:] rather than df.loc[1]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert the `index` to a series so it can support vectorized `datetime` operations and check which years are not `2019` using [`Series.ne`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ne.html)

```
# df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
df[df.index.to_series().dt.year.ne(2019)]

               HEAT/HOTWATER
2015-12-31       169457.0
2016-12-31       155578.0
2017-12-31       152009.0
2018-12-31       153277.0
```

---

Or simply `df[df.index.year != 2019]`, as the index is already a `DatetimeIndex` as pointed out by @piRSquared in the comments

Comment: thanks! this worked for me. what would be the code if it were a column instead of index?

Comment: This is sufficient `df[df.index.year != 2019]`

Comment: @ChristianTorres `df[df['created_date'].dt.year.ne(2019)]`

Comment: @piRSquared how would it look like if it were for two years, ie. 2019 and 2010, i tried `df[df['created_date'].dt.year.ne(2019,2010)]` but it didnt work

Comment: @ChristianTorres `df[df['created_date'].year.isin([2019,2010])]`

Comment: thanks @piRSquared, of course its a `DatetimeIndex`!